# Merge two list of dictionary based on key values

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I have two list of dictionary:

```
a =[{ 'id': "1", 'date': "2017-01-24" },{ 'id': "2", 'date': "2018-01-24" },{ 'id': "3", 'date': "2019-01-24" }]
b =[{ 'id': "1", 'name': "abc" },{ 'id': "2",'name': "xyz"},{ 'id': "4",'name': "ijk"}]
```

I want to merge these  dictionaries based on id and the result should be:

```
[{ 'id': "1", 'date': "2017-01-24",'name': "abc" },{ 'id': "2", 'date': "2018-01-24",'name': "xyz" },{ 'id': "3", 'date': "2019-01-24" },{ 'id': "4",'name': "ijk"}]
```

How can I do this without iterating  in python?

Comment: Why can't you iterate?

Comment: Those are lists, you *have* to iterate. Maybe you think there's a loophole where you don't consider a comprehension an iteration, but it still is an iteration. *Somewhere* you are looking at each item in turn.

Comment: I have edited my question.  If one key is not in another how to get the result.

Answer (score 4):

since the dicts are stored in list, you'll either have to iterate or use a vectorized approach such as pandas.... for example:

```
import pandas as pd
a =[{ 'id': "1", 'date': "2017-01-24" },{ 'id': "2", 'date': "2018-01-24" }]
b =[{ 'id': "1", 'name': "abc" },{ 'id': "2",'name': "xyz"}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
out = df1.merge(df2, on='id').to_dict('r')
```

result:

```
[{'id': '1', 'date': '2017-01-24', 'name': 'abc'}, {'id': '2', 'date': '2018-01-24', 'name': 'xyz'}]
```

without testing I'm not sure how this compares speed-wise to just simply iterating. It may take long to iterate, but pandas also has to construct the dataframe and convert output to dict so there's a tradeoff